# How can I make entity framework switch between using an Oracle DB and SQL Server DB?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, oracle, entity-framework-6

I have web application built using MVC with Entity Framework 6 database first to target an Oracle database.  That uses Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework, and it works as expected.  But I now have the same database/table structure on a SQL Server, and I have to give the user the option to pick which database they wish to use.  So before the user logs in, they will pick from a drop-down which DB they are using.

Does anybody know any resources or information about how I can modify things so I can change which DB is getting used based on this input?  I have no clue how to go about doing this, I have tried extensive googling, but I can't get anywhere with it.  Can anyone help?

I can provide more info if needed.

Comment: Normally, [changing the connection string is enough](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12507618/861716).

Comment: I've tried that, I get the following error when I do so: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection' to type 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection'.